# Changing Script Source on Key Press

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to get script src="jsmovermap1.js" to change to script src="jsmovermap2.js" when the user clicks UP on their keyboard. I seem to have this working when you look at page elements, but the page is not updating to the js source. Do you have any advice on how to overcome this?

Many thanks!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ireland Map</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map">
</div>

<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="jsmovermap1.js" id="s1"></script>

<script>
x=1;
alert(x);
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
if (evt.keyCode === 38) {
alert('The "UP" key is being held down...?');
x=x+1;
alert(x); 
s1.src="jsmovermap"+(x)+".js" 
//s1.src = s1.src.replace("jsmovermap1.js","jsmovermap"+(x)+".js");

}
if (evt.keyCode === 40) {
alert('The "DOWN" key is being held down...?');
x=x-1;
if(x<0){
x=0}
alert(x);
}

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("s1").src = "new src here";`.

Comment: Tried that man, still not getting any look with it :-(

Comment: Try loading a new script tag on the fly then instead of changing existing tag.